# How to return the index (or column) lable of a value if column (or index) is known in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How can I return the lable of a column if the row is knows as well as the value?

I have  a pandas dataframe with rows called "A", "B", "C" and Column called "X", "Y", "Z". Knowing a value being in row (e.g. A), I want to have the Column returned. Looking at the example I want to have "X" returned, when I  know that the value is "1" in Row "A". How can this be achieved?

```
data=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
d=pd.DataFrame(data, ["A", "B", "C"], ["X", "Y", "Z"])

   X  Y  Z
A  1  2  3
B  4  5  6
C  7  8  9
```

Comment: can you add an example too? thanks

Comment: `df.loc['A', :]` ? or `df.loc['A', 'X']`?

Comment: This won't help returning the label. I only get back the row or the cell values but not the lables. I only need the lables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know `1` is in `A`, use `loc` and get the resulting index

```
s = df.loc['A'].eq(1)
s[s].index
```

which returns

```
Index(['X'], dtype='object')
```

If you know there is only one cell with value `1` in your row, then use `.item()`

```
>>> s[s].index.item()
'X'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can using `dot`

```
d.eq(1).dot(d.columns).loc[lambda x : x!='']
A    X
dtype: object
```